# How can I get an access token for an Org when the user is signed into a different Org?

Tags: oauth2, authentication, authorization, multi-org

My managed package needs to access data from multiple Orgs.  For example, say a user has 2 accounts: 1 in Org A, and 1 in Org B.  When the user is logged in to Org A, they need to see data from both Org A and Org B.  I experimented with obtaining an access token for Org B while the user was logged in to Org A.  I created a web service that handled this process by using the Web Server OAuth flow.  However, the problem I ran into was that at the point of making the initial request to get the authorization code, https://login.salesforces.com/services/oauth2/authorize, that is in the context of the current logged in user.  So it never asks the user to log in to Org B since the user has already has approved access to our connected app in Org A.  I thought that the OAuth connected app approval process might be independent of the context of the current logged in user, but that is not the case.  Is there a way to get around that?  Is there another OAuth flow that would work better?  or is there another way of achieving this?

EDIT:
Additional requirement: For each user that issues a cross-org query for data, the query needs to respect their security settings.

Comment: Have you looked at using Named Credentials for the integration? See [Salesforce to Salesforce integration using Named Credential](http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/salesforce-to-salesforce-integration-using-named-credentials-in-just-5-lines-of-code/)

Comment: Thanks @DanielBallinger, I did not know about this option.  Another requirement I forgot to mention is that for each user that issues a query cross-org, I need to respect their security settings.  This looks like it's creating the connection with the admin's privileges.  I'll update the question with those reqs.  Not sure if there is a way of handling that with this solution

Comment: @DanielBallinger -Also, it looks like when you set up the authentication provider, specifically the callback urls and user setup, this is specific to MY orgs.  I need this to work for all orgs that install my managed package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option was for me to use the username and password OAuth flow for cross-Org connections.  That way, I was able to prompt the user for the username, password and security token to request the access token through my APEX controller in a single request.  I can then just store the access token in a cookie or local storage.  With this, you also need to add a CORS whitelist entry in your target Org(s).  So if I'm in Org A and want to call the SalesForce REST endpoint in Orgs B and C, I need to add a CORS whitelist entry in Orgs B and C that refers to Org A, i.e. https://[OrgAInstance].salesforce.com.  You can also use wildcards here if you wish.